# fail to manage nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I've stuck managing nested attributes. I'm a new guy to rails and would be very grateful for any advise or pointing on my mistakes. So I have a model Ticket like this( it also has enum integer field status, references stuff_id body and so on )

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Generator
  has_paper_trail only:[:stuff_id, :status], on:[:update] 
  has_many :replies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
end
```

Also I have Reply model

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
  validates :ticket_id, :body, presence: true
end
```

My target is to give an opportunity for stuff to create a reply for a ticket and optionally change status for a ticket. Currently I try to manage it this way:
routes.rb

```
resources :tickets do
  patch 'stuff_update', on: :member
  resources :replies
end
```

dashboards_controller.rb

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :authorize  
  before_action :method 

  def opened       
  end 

  protected 
  def method
   @tickets = Ticket.send(action_name.to_sym).includes(:replies)
  end
  def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:status, replies_attributes: [:body])
  end
end
```

tickets_controller.rb

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  #before_action :authorize, only:[:stuff_update]
  before_action :load_ticket, only:[:show, :update, :stuff_update]  

  respond_to :js

  def stuff_update
    @ticket.update(ticket_params)          
  end
  protected
  def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :subject, :email, :status, :body, :department, :stuff_id, replies_attributes: [:id, :body])
  end

  def load_ticket
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

And finally view

```
-@tickets.each do |t|
  .panel.panel-default
    p=t.subject
    =form_for t,{ url: "/tickets/#{t.id}/stuff_update"}, {method: :patch} do |f|
      = f.label :status, class: 'label_hidden'
      = f.select :status, Ticket.statuses.keys, {}, {class:'form-control'}
      = f.fields_for t.replies.build do |ff|  
        = ff.label :body
        = ff.text_field :body 
      = f.submit "Submit"
```

I've got an error for unpermitted parameter reply. Also it seems to me there are plenty mistakes in my code besides this error. I desperately need help. Please help me to get through this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution I've found is pretty simple

```
-@tickets.each do |t|
  -t.replies.build
  .panel.panel-default
    p=t.subject
    =form_for t, url: "/tickets/#{t.id}/stuff_update", method: :patch do |f|
      p
        = f.label :status, class: 'label_hidden'
        = f.select :status, Ticket.statuses.keys, {}, {class:'form-control'}
      p      
        = f.fields_for :replies do |ff|  
          = ff.label :body
          = ff.text_field :body 
      = f.submit "Submit"
```

everything else is pretty identic.